# How to hide element after mouse unhover 5 seconds ago?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousehover

```css
#div1 {
  display: block;
}

#div2 {
  display: none;
}

#container:hover > #div2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Here I have a bit of code that, whenever, `Div1` is hovered by the mouse, `Div2` shows. When not hovering over `Div1` or `Div2`, `Div2` hides itself.

How can I make it that when the mouse is hovering over `Div1`, but has not been moved for 5 seconds, `Div2` hides itself?

Comment: You need to use JS for that

Answer (score 2):

You need to use javascript or jquery to do this work. When `#div1` hovered, show `#div2` and when it unhovered use javascript [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function to hide `#div2` after 5 seconds.

```
$("#div1").hover(function(){
  $("#div2").show();
}, function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
  }, 5000);
});
```

If you hover in and out quickly for multiple time, the interval doesn't work properly. You should store interval in variable and on every unhover event use `clearInterval()` to removing previous interval.

```
var timer;
$("#div1").hover(function(){
  $("#div2").show();
}, function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```js
var timer;
$("#div1").hover(function(){
  $("#div2").show();
}, function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
#div2 { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to hover in and out quickly 4-5 times. It'll not work as expected

Answer (score 2):

The other 2 answers are incomplete. Try to hover on the link twice or thrice within 5 seconds and the logic breaks. Try this, and obviously, remove CSS.

```js
var intervalIsGoingOn = false;
    
    document.getElementById('div1').onmouseover = function() {
       document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
    }
    
    document.getElementById('div1').onmouseout = function() {
       if(intervalIsGoingOn) return;
       intervalIsGoingOn = true;
       setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
          intervalIsGoingOn = false;
       }, 1000);
    };
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2" style="display:none">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the current HTML structure, hiding a sibling element, this is perfectly possible with CSS transitions:

```css
#div1 {
  display: block;
}

#div2 {
  /* Using opacity to hide the element, since animating from
     'display: none' or 'visibility: hidden' is not possible: */
  opacity: 0;

  /* Setting the transition-delay to five seconds (5s), for
     the non-hovered state of the element: */
  transition-delay: 5s;
}

#container:hover>#div2 {
  /* Updating the opacity to 1; to show the element with
     no transparency (adjust to taste): */
  opacity: 1;
  /* setting the property to animate ('opacity'), over
     a period 0.3 seconds with a linear transition: */
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
```

If, however, you need to hide a previous sibling element it's possible to *emulate* the behaviour using CSS and flex-boxes; this approach only emulates the behaviour, as the elements remain in their original positions in the source and are re-ordered using the flex-box `order`:

```css
#container {
  /* displays the element as a flex container element,
     able to contain, and display, flex items
     appropriately: */
  display: flex;
  /* sets the flex-direction to follow a top-to-bottom
     layout (sort of emulating 'display: block': */
  flex-direction: column;
}

#div2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 5s;
  /* Positions the element ahead of elements with
     an 'order' property of 0 or greater (the
     default 'order' property is 1):*/
  order: -1;
}

#container:hover>#div2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var delayMillis = 5000; //5 seconds

setTimeout(function() {
  //your code.
}, delayMillis);
```

Code will be executed with 5 second delay.

```js
$("#div1").hover(function(){
    $('#div2').show();
},function(){
    $('#div2').hide();
});

setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

function fade_out() {
  $("#div2").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It'll create a whole mess if you add that in an event handler. Go ahead and try yourself

Comment: you were right it was too complicated. I update a post i think this will work. :D